# Shared folder not seen in VirtualBox: how to fix?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, network-shares, shared-folders

I have a `Windows 7 64bit guest` on a `Windows 7 64bits host` *VirtualBox 5.0.26.*

I exposed the `c:\tmp` directory on the host in the `shared folders` like so:

[image: c:\tmp]

However, in the guest *I don't see this directory* in the `network` resources:

[image: guest network resources]

### Anything I can do to access the shared folder?

Comment: Did you install the Guest Addition?

Comment: This likely will not solve your problem but you should consider upgrading to 5.1.2

Comment: Thanks @Darius for your answer. Umounting+remounting VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.16.iso (couldn't find a VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.26.iso) and then executing the installer, solved the problem.

Comment: Any critical problems with 5.0.26 that 5.1.2 solves, @Ramhound ?

Comment: @boardrider Chnagelog is public